# Gtk C Application - Set PWD so pictures work

Tags: c, linux, gtk, pwd

I have a simple Gtk GUI application written in C. I want to be able to render external images within a frame in my main window. The code for this is as follows:

```
GtkWidget myImage;
myImage = gtk_image_new_from_file("assets/image.png");
gtk_fixed_put(FTK_FIXED(frame), myImage, 0, 0));
```

The image shows as expected, but only if I `cd` into the directory where it exists. ie:

```
cd /tmp/bin/
./gtktest
```

If I run it from another location, like so, the image is never found.

```
/tmp/bin/gtktest
```

Is there a way to have the application set the present working directory (PWD) to the location of the binary itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a relative path to `cwd` but you need to use either a relative path based on the location of the program binary or an absolute path based on the filesystem's  root like `/usr/lib/yourprogram/assets`.

If you want to build a relative path based on the location of the binary, which might be more flexible in some situations, then you should use `dirname()`. Like this:

```
char *my_location = dirname(argv[0]); // argv[0] contains the path to the binary
```

Check `man 3 dirname` for more info.

Comment: Will also mention that, if you are using a GNU build system, you might configure the path during build time, like `./configure --with-assets=/usr/lib/` . This is the way to go if you want to create OS packages from the software

Answer (score 2):

Put the assets inside a [`GResource`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GResource.html) and compile them directly into your program.

Comment: While hek2mgl's response is the most direct, this approach is what I'll likely end up using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could call [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) from inside your Gtk program, or its Glib wrapper [g_chdir](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-chdir)